# undefined method `manage_gems`

Tags: rubygems

On my ubuntu 8.04, I did a

```
gem update --system
```

and now everytime i try to run the gem command line from console, i get the error:

```
/usr/bin/gem:10: undefined method `manage_gems' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
```

What's going on?  My version of rubygem was very old, but at least it was working before.  How do I fix the above problem or roll back to my earlier version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-installed ruby gems to fix this